# Web scraping with Python and Pandas - Pagination

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, pagination

With this short code I can get data from the table:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_html('https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/middle-long/800-metres/indoor/men/senior/2023?regionType=world&timing=electronic&page=1&bestResultsOnly=false&oversizedTrack=regular',parse_dates=True)

df[0].to_csv('2023_I_M_800.csv')
```

I am trying to get data from all pages or a determinated number of them but since this website doesn't use lu or li elementsIdon'tknow exacxtly how to built it.

Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the url contains the page number, why not just making a loop and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) ?

> `https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/middle-long/800-metres/indoor/men/senior/2023?regionType=world&timing=electronic&**page=1**&bestResultsOnly=false&oversizedTrack=regular

```
import pandas as pd
​
F, L = 1, 4 # first and last pages
​
dico = {}
for page in range(F, L+1):
    url = f'https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/middle-long/800-metres/indoor/men/senior/2023?regionType=world&timing=electronic&page={page}&bestResultsOnly=false&oversizedTrack=regular'
    sub_df = pd.read_html(url, parse_dates=True)[0]
    sub_df.insert(0, "page_number", page)
    dico[page] = sub_df
    ​
out = pd.concat(dico, ignore_index=True)
# out.to_csv('2023_I_M_800.csv') # <- uncomment this line to make a .csv
```

NB : You can access each `sub_df` separately by using *key-indexing notation* : `dico[num_page]`.

Output :

```
print(out)

     page_number  Rank  ...         Date Results Score
0              1     1  ...  22 JAN 2023          1230
1              1     2  ...  22 JAN 2023          1204
2              1     3  ...  29 JAN 2023          1204
3              1     4  ...  27 JAN 2023          1192
4              1     5  ...  28 JAN 2023          1189
..           ...   ...  ...          ...           ...
395            4   394  ...  21 JAN 2023           977
396            4   394  ...  28 JAN 2023           977
397            4   398  ...  27 JAN 2023           977
398            4   399  ...  28 JAN 2023           977
399            4   399  ...  29 JAN 2023           977

[400 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you. I get that SyntaxError at line 3 (​F , L = 1, 6): Invalid non-printable character U+200B

Comment: If it's the case, then even the answer accepted will give you an error.

Comment: OK. It works now. I deleted and I typed again that line since it seemed to be some strange space that was giving that error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for page in range(1, 10):
    df=pd.read_html(f'https://www.worldathletics.org/records/toplists/middle-long/800-metres/indoor/men/senior/2023?regionType=world&timing=electronic&page={page}&bestResultsOnly=false&oversizedTrack=regular',parse_dates=True)

    df[0].to_csv(f'2023_I_M_800_page_{page}.csv')
```

Comment: You can even store all the dfs in a list, concatenate them and then save one big csv instead of one csv per page

Comment: Thank you. It works. In fact that was my idea, to concatenate the different tables in an unique csv file.